# SQL error during Symfony 2 application login

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am doing some work on an older project that was developed using Symfony 2.
Login is failing with:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

This happens in the Doctrine repository for the User entity, specifically at the call to $user = $q->getSingleResult();

```
$q = $this
  ->createQueryBuilder( 'u' )
  ->where( 'u.email = :email' )
  ->setParameter( 'email', $email )
  ->getQuery();
$user = $q->getSingleResult(); // Fails here.
```

What is really odd is that I can access the database using the console.

```
app$ console doctrine:query:sql "select * from users where email='username@domain'"
```

That works fine.
I've searched for this and pretty much all of the answers are that the database connection configuration is wrong. Seems unlikely since I can access the database fine with the mysql command and with the console doctrine:query command.

Environment:
* Ubuntu 18.04
* Apache 2.4.29
* PHP 7.2.7
* Symfony 2.5.6

Comment: I think problem is related to database_host, please re-check

Comment: I've checked it numerous times. Besides, it works from the console which uses the same configuration.

Comment: did you try using a different browser?

Comment: No. This is a server-side error.